# Login via Azure active directory from web form .aspx

Tags: asp.net, authentication, webforms, azure-active-directory, federation

We got web form based application with database driven user login.
Now we want to switch to windows Azure AD. I know i can create a new project and add authentication mechanism to use sign on using Azure AD (easy enough).
But what i want is to modify my existing login mechanism to support Azure AD as well with old style login.
So how can i do a simple aspx page code behind to login in Azure AD. I tried using ADAL library.
I can popup login window via this (first line)

```
AuthenticationContext cnts = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/myTenant.onmicrosoft.com");
```

but how to get confirmation of login ??
tried below but no luck

```
AuthenticationResult authRes = cnts.AcquireToken("http://androidclienturi_a/", "a0cbaead-929b-4f89-8665-b02bb1f49d01", new Uri("http://localhost:55263/Default.aspx"));
```

Extensive research have been done, i have almost seen all forums and reltaed blogs, but i don't want to use MVC and don't want to start web application from scratch to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this is work or not in Azure AD but This is the code which is works in dedicated server. Just changed variable names with your actual server configuration.

```
Dim lbAuthenticated As Boolean = False
Dim loPrincipalContext As System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext = Nothing

loPrincipalContext = New System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext(ContextType.ApplicationDirectory,
                                                                                                 lsLDAPIPAddress,
                                                                                                 lsLDAPContainer,
                                                                                                 ContextOptions.Negotiate,
                                                                                                 lsLDAPAdminUsername,
                                                                                                 lsLDAPAdminPassword)

lbAuthenticated = loPrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials(lsLDAPAttribute & "=" & fsUsername & "," & lsLDAPPath,
                                                                     fsPassword,
                                                                     ContextOptions.SimpleBind)
```